# Ajuda com erro Trying to get property of non-object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Eu tenho um relacionamento, onde tento pegar o nome de um professor, eu consigo retornar o id dele, porém quando tento retornar o nome ele me dá a mensagem Trying to get property of non-object
Meu código está assim:
Model Curso.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Curso extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'professor_id',
        'nome'
    ];

    public function professor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Professor);
    }
}
```

Model Professor

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Professor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome',
        'data_nascimento'
    ];

    public function cursos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Curso);
    }
}
```

CursoController

```
 */
public function index()
{
    $cursos = Curso::all();

    return view('curso.index', compact('cursos'));
}
```

E meu index.blade.php

```
  @foreach($cursos as $value)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->nome}}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->professor->nome }}</td>
    <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
```

Aqui ele dá o erro, exatamente em  {{ $Value->professors->nome }}
Minha tabela se chama professors a propósito.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sempre o carregamento adiantado, porque, gera somente ***2*** `SQL` e com isso não há *perca no desempenho*, **exemplo** da modificação:

```
public function index()
{
    $cursos = Curso::with('professor')->get();

    return view('curso.index', compact('cursos'));
}
```

outros pontos tem erro de digitação, exemplo não é só `App\Curso`, ou é `"App\Curso"` ou `App\Curso::class`, então modifiquei as duas classes:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Curso extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['professor_id','nome'];

    public function professor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Professor::class);
    }
}
```

e

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Professor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome','data_nascimento'];

    public function cursos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Curso::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Minha tabela se chama professors com S no fim, coloco igual?

Comment: @LintonJunior na verdade ali é o nome do método que no caso eu mudei agora para `professor` !!! ? verifique

Comment: (1/1) RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [professor] on model [flexpeak\Curso].
Retornou isso

Comment: Tinha erro de digitação @LintonJunior dá uma olhada!

Comment: @LintonJunior mais uma alteração.

Comment: Agora funcionou, putz, cara.
Que grande ajuda.
O erro estava somente em return $this->hasMany(\App\Curso::class); e return $this->belongsTo(\App\Professor::class);?

Comment: Aceito, amigo.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Virgilio, você pode me dar mais uma ajuda?
No create e edit, como eu faço pra chamar e nas views correspondentes como eu faço pra chamar um select?

Comment: @LintonJunior cada pergunta a gente responde uma duvida, então, pode abrir uma nova pergunta para uma nova duvida sem problemas! Ok!